# Struggling with Scrapy pagination

Tags: web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

At the moment have got a bit of the Frankenstein code (consisting of Beautifulsoup and Scrapy parts) that seem to be doing a job in terms of the reading the info from page 1 urls. Shall try to redo everything in Scrapy as soon as pagination issue resolved.

So what codes is meant to do:

1. Read all subcategories (BeautifulSoup part)

The rest are Scrapy code parts

2. Using the above urls read sub-subcategories.
3. Extract the last page number and loop over the above urls.
4. Extract the necessary product info from the above urls.

All except part 3 do seem to work.

Have tried to use the below code to extract the last page number but not sure how to integrate it into the main code

```
def parse_paging(self, response):
        try:
            for next_page in ('?pn=1' + response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination pull-left"]/noscript/a/text()').extract()[-1]):
                print(next_page)
#                yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page))
        except:
            pass
```

The below is the main code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

category_list = []
sub_category_url = []

root_url = 'https://uk.rs-online.com/web'
page = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
cat_up = [a.find_all('a') for a in soup.find_all('div',class_='horizontalMenu sectionUp')]
category_up = [item for sublist in cat_up for item in sublist]
cat_down = [a.find_all('a') for a in soup.find_all('div',class_='horizontalMenu sectionDown')]
category_down = [item for sublist in cat_down for item in sublist]
for c_up in category_up:
    sub_category_url.append('https://uk.rs-online.com' + c_up['href'])
for c_down in category_down:
    sub_category_url.append('https://uk.rs-online.com' + c_down['href'])
#   print(k)


class subcategories(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'subcategories'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = sub_category_url
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.card.js-title a::href').extract() #xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'js-tile')]/a/@href").
        for p in products:
            url = urljoin(response.url, p)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)
    def parse_product(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('tr.resultRow'):
            yield {
                'product': quote.css('div.row.margin-bottom a::text').getall(),
                'stock_no': quote.css('div.stock-no-label a::text').getall(),
                'brand': quote.css('div.row a::text').getall(),
                'price': quote.css('div.col-xs-12.price.text-left span::text').getall(),
                'uom': quote.css('div.col-xs-12.pack.text-left span::text').getall(),
            }
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(subcategories)
process.start()
```

Would be exceptionally grateful if you could provides any hints on how to deal with the above issue.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: why do you have two `def parse(self, response)` in the code

Comment: apologies. should have been parse_product. Have edited the code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to extract next page number by using this
and then construct next page url using this number.

```
next_page_number = response.css('.nextPage::attr(ng-click)').re_first('\d+')
```

Comment: This one helped. Thanks

Comment: would you recommend any optimization changes? There are around 1mn products on the website and the comments runs good few hours. I know that the above is far from being perfect, so there are may be some things can be done to improve the performance?

Comment: it depends on many things like: site architecture, your bandwidth, website antibot settings(eg. maximum amount of connections, captchas, etc), proxy pool if needed, etc.
First of all try to play with threads amount.

Regarding crawler architecture - best way is to open several product categories at once and then follow pagination of each.